# JavaScripts equivalent to jQuery document click with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the JavaScript equivalent to this jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-star', function (event) {
    //event will return the .add-star
})
```

Markup looks like this

```
<div class="add-star">
    <svg>
        <path />
    </svg>
</div>
```

When I do `document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {...` the `e.target` gets me the `path` not the parent `add-star`. From what I know with the jQuery way it bubbles up on the event looking for the class specified and returns that in the event. But there is no class specified with the JS event, so it returns just the immediate clicked element, the `path` from the svg.

How would I return `add-star` from the js event?

Comment: If you cannot attach to the desired target directly, you have to check the parent chain manually (this is what JQ does for you when you delegate).

Comment: If you only will ever have 1 case of "add-star" on a page, you can use this as a simplified version of the below processes: 
 document.getElementsByClassName("add-star")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event){...});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy. You just use `.matches()` on each element starting at `e.target`, traversing through each `.parentNode` until the bound element. When/if a match is found, you call the function.

So create a function that receives the callback and returns a new function handles this operation.

```
function delegate(selector, handler) {
  return function(event) {
    var el = event.target;
    do {
      if (el.matches(selector)) {
        handler.call(el, event);
      }
    } while ((el = el.parentNode) && el !== this);
  };
}
```

Then call that function to create the handler.

```
document.addEventListener('click', delegate('.add-star', function (event) {
    //event will return the .add-star
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two main ways of handling events here, the event delegation method is similar to what your jQuery example is doing so I'll make that #1. This method uses [e.target.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to accomplish checking for an element that might not exist. The second method is for more traditional elements and uses [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

### Method 1 delegated events

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!e.target.matches('.add-star')) { return }

  // do stuff
});
```

### Method 2 non-dynamic selectors

```
let ele = document.querySelector('.add-star');
ele.addEventListener('click', e => { // do stuff });
```